# Are threads suitable for this situation or is there is any other easy concurrency framework in Java 8 useful here?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, java-8

While searching through this site and also on the web, I haven't managed to find pinpointed solution to my problem, and therefore I am posting it here.

Within my Java application, there is a list with million objects, and I need give a name to each element, based upon some conditions. By using single thread, this is a bottle neck in the program. As the naming operation can be done independently, I am planning to create 4 threads (based on the processor cores I have). The idea is to divide the list into 4 parts and allocate each part to a thread.

Now the question is, as I am using Java 8.

1. Can I achieve the above scenario by using basic multi-threading with *Runnable* and *Thread* classes? Will this automatically allocate the threads to each core?
2. Or, is there any other concurrency framework available in Java 8, that can do this efficiently?

My objective is to distribute the job to all the cores.

Thank you.

**SOLUTION:** *Parallelism* didn't worked for my situation. The CPU utilization is 100%, but the execution got hanged (reasons unknown). Also it has a restriction that I need to use only *final* variables when using the streams.

I have solved my problem by using *ForkJoinPool* of *ExecutorService* interface. My code is now utilizing multicores and I can see significant speedup.

Comment: Have you considered a parallel stream?

Comment: @RobinTopper Just googled about it, and it's looks promising. But, I will wait for other's suggestions before deciding.

Comment: That’s what you get for free when using a parallel stream. But keep in mind that regardless of what you do, the best you can ever get with four cores, is a speedup factor of four. If the time needed for the sequential processing of the million objects hurts, will ¼ of that time be satisfying?

Comment: @Holger I agree with you, at the moment the processing growth is quadratic, and I have no way to make it linear. Therefore, I thought of dividing the task, so that at least I can gain something from concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

You should use parallelism:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html

That way JVM will manage it for you.

EDIT: The JVM will tell you the number of available processors with:

```
int i = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()
```

With that you can know the available threads to make the multithreading. Is something not so easy to do but neither too hard but I think that it doesn't worth: Parallelism is done to do exactly what you have to do....

At the end the problem with java8's paralellism is more the missuse of it than itself...

Disclaimer: I've done some programs which manage that sort of multithreading of processing an entire list of items with a set of threads on java6 that today are running in production enviroment everyday and not a single one using java8's parallelism. But if I had had the chance of using paralellim I would had use it...

Seriously, at least TEST it, you only have to add the `.paralellism` to your code, if it matches your requirements and works well for you use it... Else take a coffe or a beer and prepare yourself to do something that will cost you a day of work...

Comment: Thank you, I have already looked at it, but it has it's own drawbacks. Can you explain me why I can't do that with normal multi-threading??

Comment: @Brainy which drawbacks?

Comment: @StefanZobel probably, I can reply to you once I understood, what it is affecting the performance of my code.

Comment: @inigoD Thanks for detailed explanation, will try with parallellism.

Comment: @StefanZobel streams restrict me to use only final variables, but that is not possible in my application.

Comment: @inigoD I have solved the problem using _ForkJoinPool_. Parallelism didn't worked.